# Java Graphics.fillXxx() in combination with Graphics2D.scale()

Tags: java, drawing, graphics2d

I have this program:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class TestLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestLine().start();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void start() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new CarthPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class CarthPanel extends JComponent {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;

            int w = gg.getClipBounds().width;
            int h = gg.getClipBounds().height;
            System.out.println("(w,h)=(" + w + "," + h + ")");

            gg.translate(w - 1, 0); // <<< when uncommenting both lines, mirroring applies
            gg.scale(-1.0, 1.0);    //

            paintTest(gg, w, h);
        }

        private static void paintTest(Graphics2D g, int w, int h) {
            // black background
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

            // colored corners
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 0);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(0, 199, 10, 199);
            g.drawLine(0, 199, 0, 189);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.drawLine(189, 0, 199, 0);
            g.drawLine(199, 0, 199, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.drawLine(189, 199, 199, 199);
            g.drawLine(199, 199, 199, 189);

            // yellow squares
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.drawRect(3, 3, 10, 10);
            g.fillRect(186, 3, 11, 11);
            g.fillRect(3, 186, 11, 11);
            g.drawRect(186, 186, 10, 10);

            String chars = "ABC";
            g.setFont(Font.decode("Arial 72"));
            Rectangle2D rect = g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(chars, g);
            g.drawString(chars, (int) (200 - rect.getWidth()) / 2, (int) (200 - rect.getHeight()));
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this program once with two particular lines commented in and then once with the same lines commented out (see the code), then you get to see this:

[[image: Graphics.scale() and Graphics.translate()[1]]

If you didn't spot the problem, here's a zoomed pic:

[image: Zoomed]

One would expect the image to be perfectly mirrored. This is true for all strokes and hollow shapes (= drawXxx() methods). All filled shapes however (= fillXxx() methods) are drawn exactly one pixel to the left of where I expect them; e.g. the filled yellow rectangles, and you can also notice that the black background has shifted, as seen by the white line at the right border.

Is this a bug or is this intended? I suspect that it has something to do with the difference how "width" and "height" are being handled in drawXxx() and fillXxx() methods:

- drawRect(x,y,w,h) results in a hollow rectangle with X-axis boundaries x and x+w, so the rectangle is w+1 pixels wide.
- fillRect(x,y,w,h) results in a filled rectangle with X-axis boundaries x and x+w-1, so the rectangle is w pixels wide.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a bug, it is not a feature :)
Surely it is not intended, the mirrored image should be perfect, there's no reason why it shouldn't.

There is a way to use BufferedImage to render on it normally, and then drawing this BufferedImage flipped, the only drawback is a little performance influence and not well looking text drawn using LCD subpixeling.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class TestLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestLine().start();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void start() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new CarthPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class CarthPanel extends JComponent {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;

//            System.out.println("(w,h)=(" + w + "," + h + ")");

            gg.translate(getWidth(), 0); // <<< when uncommenting both lines, mirroring applies
            gg.scale(-1.0, 1.0);    //

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            try {
                paintTest(img.createGraphics());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }



        private void paintTest(Graphics2D g) {
            // black background
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            // colored corners
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 0);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(0, 199, 10, 199);
            g.drawLine(0, 199, 0, 189);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.drawLine(189, 0, 199, 0);
            g.drawLine(199, 0, 199, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.drawLine(189, 199, 199, 199);
            g.drawLine(199, 199, 199, 189);

            // yellow squares
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.drawRect(3, 3, 10, 10);
            g.fillRect(186, 3, 11, 11);
            g.fillRect(3, 186, 11, 11);
            g.drawRect(186, 186, 10, 10);

            String chars = "ABC";
            g.setFont(Font.decode("Arial 72"));
            Rectangle2D rect = g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(chars, g);
            g.drawString(chars, (int) (200 - rect.getWidth()) / 2, (int) (200 - rect.getHeight()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "all the drawXXX are wrong"? From my tests it's clearly the filled shapes that are shifted, not the outlined shapes. You are right that BufferedImage's graphics context does work! So this must be a bug in the Java component's graphics context.

Comment: I think your example is almost correct, `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `gg.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);`.

Comment: I guess your answer is not correct after all. Whenever you take a graphics context from a BufferedImage and then scale/translate it, the fillXxx() methods also result in pixelshifts. In your example, you drew everything on the BufferedImage directly (without any transformation), and then scaled/translated the entire thing in one go when drawing the image onto the Java Component graphics object. This is indeed working, but your assumption that this is related to the graphics context itself is wrong: the bug is there whenever you draw on a scaled/translated context - drawXxx() is pixelshifted.

Comment: @Timmos You are right, there is an issue with the Graphics regardless of where it come from.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, rather a hypothesis - the "contains(x,y)" of a rectangle will be `true` for the sides which forms the (x,y) corner of the rect and `false` for the sides making the (maxx, maxy) corner. Demo:

```
Rectangle r=new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
System.out.println(r.contains(0, 5)); // true
System.out.println(r.contains(5, 0)); // true
System.out.println(r.contains(10, 5)); // false
System.out.println(r.contains(5, 10)); // false
```

The hypothesis is that `fillRect` will not consider the "max sides" as inside points to be filled.

To assess the hypothesis, I'd suggest you to try using a `GeneralPath` which defines the same rectangle and see it there is any difference in filling it. GeneralPath should be forbidden to make any assumption on "the right-top borders are out of the shape's interior"